# Factoring Django URLs using Python wizardry

Tags: python, django, django-urls

### Situation

---

I am using a Django plugin, [django-ajax-validation](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation), which handle for me the form validation when building AJAX forms with jQuery.

Basically, it does what it says. However, now that I am willing to implement more form in my application I need several URL for the AJAX requests. For now my `ajax/urls.py` contains:

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('ajax_validation.views',
    url(r'^validate/foo$', 'validate', {'form_class':FooForm}, name='validate-form-foo'),
    url(r'^validate/bar$', 'validate', {'form_class':BarForm}, name='validate-form-bar'),
)
```

But this looks ugly to me and quite difficult to maintain. Here is what I want to do:

```py
FORMS = {
    'foo': FooForm,
    'bar': BarForm,
}

urlpatterns = patterns('ajax_validation.views',
    url(r'^validate/(?P<label>[^/]+)$', 'validate', {'form_class':FORMS[label]}, name='validate-form'),
)
```

But it doesn't work, obviously.

### What might help

---

From the documentation:

> The URL can take any arguments(named, or unamed), and you can also
>   provide a callback function, this function is given request, *args,
>   and **kwargs and should return a dictionary which is passed to the
>   form constructor.

From the source:

```py
def validate(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = kwargs.pop('form_class')
    extra_args_func = kwargs.pop('callback', lambda request, *args, **kwargs: {})
    ...
```

### Questions

---

- What is the good way of *factoring* such URLs, if there is any ? Not having to edit the plugi source would be a good thing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I don't see any reason you can't build an args sequence for the `patterns` constructor:

```
FORMS = {
    'foo': FooForm,
    'bar': BarForm,
}

validate_patterns = [url(r'^validate/%s' % label, 'validate', {'form_class': FORMS[label]}, name='validate-form-%s' % label) for label in FORMS.iterkeys()]

urlpatterns = patterns('ajax_validation.views', *validate_patterns)
```

Alternately, you could define a single view of your own to call the plugin views appropriately:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^validate/(?P<label>[^/]+)$', 'validate_by_label', name='validate-form'),
)

views.py:
# appropriate imports for Http404, your forms, and the third party plugin validate view

FORMS = {
    'foo': FooForm,
    'bar': BarForm,
}

def validate_by_label(request, label):
    form_class = FORMS.get(label)
    if form_class is None:
        raise Http404
    else:
        return ajax_validation.views.validate(request, form_class=form_class)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does look like working. Gonna try it tomorrow and will mark as answered if so.